# IIS7 and Enforce lowercase URLs combres.axd not loaded

Tags: url, iis, iis-7, combres

I have successfully applied IIS Rule (Enforce Lowercase URL) on my website but now I have one issue our one file combres.axd stopped loading.
I tried to apply others way also which I found on stackoverflow but no success yet.
Please advice how to fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try below rule to change URL into lowercase:

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule">
  <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
</rule>
```

Below is the result:

[image]

Failed request tracing result:

[image]

If you still face and issue you could run failed request tracing in iis and check why the URL is giving you a 404 error. another thing make sure the file exists at the place with the same path and name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules